# I am trying to fetch Apexlogs using the tooling API but getting an error of "URL No Longer Exists"

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, tooling-api

```
ApexLog al = [SELECT Id, LogUserId, LogUser.Name, Request, Operation, Application, Status, StartTime, Location, LogLength FROM ApexLog LIMIT 1];
String logId = al.Id;
System.debug(logId);

// Set HTTPRequest Method
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setEndpoint(Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/sobjects/ApexLog/' + logId + '/Body');
req.setMethod('GET');


// Web service call
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

Could someone tell why is this happening?
Also the status code is 404

Comment: Your endpoint is incorrect - see doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_resources.htm

Comment: Using the same syntax as specified on the site..could you help?
What should be the correct endpoint?

Comment: Now using:
req.setEndpoint(Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v55.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexLog/' + logId + '/Body/');

Getting Error: Log Deleted

Comment: Looks like you've just answered your own question - feel free to write it up as the answer and accept it.

Comment: Hi I am still getting an error : 
"Failed to load data Log from Salesforce.com: Salesforce automatically deletes system logs 24 hours after they're generated. If the log you had open was less than 24 hours old, someone deleted it. To save logs, select File > Download Log."

However using the query editor I can see there are logs available.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one or morphing one question into another. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!